# a continuous linear functional maps the interior of a convex set to an open interval in R

Tags: functional-analysis

I want to show that

If X is a real topological vector space and $f:X\to {\Bbb R}$ is a continuous ${\Bbb R}$ - linear functional and $A$ is an open convex subset of $X$, then $f(A)$ is an open interval.

clearly $f(A)$ is an interval (because $A$ is convex and F is continuous). but I do not know why $f$ is an open map. Please hint me. thanks so much

Comment: Don't you need $f$ to be onto to be able to apply the open mapping theorem?

Comment: I think about using open mapping theorem. but for this I also need X be a frechet space and f be onto. while there are not these conditions

Answer (score 3):

In general this is false (take $f\equiv 0$).

For $f\not\equiv 0$, take any $x_0$ with $f(x_0) \neq 0$ and note $x \pm \varepsilon x_0 \in A$ for $x \in A$ and $\varepsilon$ small enough (because $A$ is open).

EDIT: Further clarification: W.l.o.g. we can assume $f(x_0) = 1$ (why?). Then the above shows $f(x) \pm \varepsilon = f(x \pm \varepsilon x_0) \in f(A)$ for $x \in A$ and $\varepsilon > 0$ small enough. This easily shows that $f(A)$ is open.

Note that we did not have to use continuity of $f$ anywhere.

Comment: why do you say "$x±εx_0\in A$ for x∈A and ε small enough"?

Comment: Have a look at the extended answer.

Comment: Please explain how do you say for $x,x_0\in A$, and ε small enough $x±εx_0∈A$ ?At the first look , I think about using convexity of A. but after a while, I understood it's not correct.

Comment: Because $A$ is open and $\varepsilon \mapsto x + \varepsilon x_0$ is continuous, the inverse image $\{\varepsilon \in \Bbb{R} \mid x + \varepsilon x_0 \in A\}$ is open.

Comment: Why is not the set $\{\epsilon | x+\epsilon x_0\in A\}  empty?$

Comment: Because it contains $0$ as $x\in A$.

Comment: @PhoemueX I think that your proof should also work in the complex case, right? Could you please explain where one needs the convexity in the (complex) case of the proof?

Comment: @Jan: Yes, a very slight modification of the proof also works in the complex case. And the convexity is not actually needed :P It suffices to just have an open set.